# Jupyter notebook throws error 'No Module named qiskit' however 'pip list' does shows qiskit as one of the installed packages under command prompt

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pip, anaconda, qiskit

I created python virtual environment using conda and switched to that environment on my windows machine.

I installed qiskit using `pip install qiskit` and I verified installation using `pip list` where it shows qiskit as one of the installed packages.

However under jupyter notebook when i tried importing the qiskit module with `import qiskit` it throws the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import qiskit

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit'
```

Qiskit version is 0.45.0 and python version is 3.12

I installed qiskit using pip in a python virtual environment on a windows machine.
In jupyter notebook i tried to import qiskit with `import qiskit` however it threw Module not found error, No module named 'qiskit'
I was expecting qiskit to be imported since all the setup looks correct

Comment: The issue probably stems from Jupyter using site packages from a different location than from where the shell is running where you ran `pip install qiskit` and `pip list`. It's hard to be 100% sure from your statements: "I installed qiskit using pip install qiskit and I verified installation using pip list where it shows qiskit as one of the installed packages." That is because you don't detail where you installed and where you ran `pip list`. If you don't want to bother sorting this further and don't mind installing again, you can run in the notebook `%pip install qiskit` and it will ...

Comment: <continued> insure it installs it to the environment where the kernel is running that is backing the active `.ipynb` file. Otherwise, you can see similar issues with different packages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67185837/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172983/8508004) or [the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841094/i-have-module-installed-but-jupyter-notebook-throws-an-error-no-module-name#comment135626774_76841132) for help trying to sort it out without reinstalling by pointing the Jupyter kernel